# how to position precisely the cursor in a bode diagram with LtSpice?

Tags: ltspice

I'm using Ltspice, and when I have a bode diagram, I have a cursor.

I'm able to move the cursor over whatever value I'm using. However, sometime I need a precise frequency. When I try to enter it in the box, it appears to be locked.

As a side question, would it be possible  to make the cursor go to the maximum peak?

Comment: You can move the cursor with the arrow keys.

Comment: thanks!! that is way better than the mouse. But is there a way to move it exactly at 105 for example?

Comment: You can only move to the points that it did a simulation for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do so. It might be noteworthy, that the lines you see are actually an interpolated view of the datapoints, so you only have a limited collection of data points available.

You can view the available data points via right click and `Mark Data Points`

[image: result with data points visible]

You can navigate your cursor to the next data point using the left and right arrow key on your keyboard.

If you just want to determine a maximum value, you can use a `.MEASURE` directive. (Use the `.op` button to place a custom directive on the schematic)

For example:

`.measure AC res1 MAX mag(V(out))`

Where:

- `AC` is the type of the simulation on which the result has to be taken
- `res1` is the name of the result
- `MAX` indicates to find the maximum
- `mag()` is for looking for the magnitude (in AC we have complex results)
- `V(out)` is the expression on which it should find the maximum

The results are available (oddly) in the Spice Error Log (View -> Spice Error Log or CTRL+L).

You'll find a line like:

> res1: MAX(mag(v(out)))=(-0.0171115dB,-3.59527°) FROM 1 TO 100000

Now that doesn't give you the frequency at which this maximum is reached.

To do that, you need another `.measure`:

`.measure AC res2 when mag(V(out))=res1`

What's happening here? It measures the time (or frequency) when the condition is true. So basically you ask "at what point is the magnitude of the output voltage equal to the `res1`", `res1` contains the maximum of the magnitude, so you ask for the point where it reaches the maximum.

And you will get:

> res2: mag(v(out))=res1 AT 1

It's not possible to do it with just one `.measure` statement.